# jacocoData missing with EclEmma & AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests

Tags: eclipse, spring, eclipse-plugin, emma

I've been trying to use EclEmma 2.1.0.201202261248 to measure integration test coverage for DAOs. Unfortunately, any test which extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests (that is, anything which actually uses part of the spring framework) throws the following exception:

07:35:11 ERROR [main] (ASMLogger.java:72) -  Exception thrown < findByFilter > exception message could not resolve property: $jacocoData of: com.asentria.asm.persistence.krp.ProductData with params  :: DataFilter{SerialNum:66,KeyNum:1967,Index1:1,Index2:2,HasPendingValue:null,OrderByDesc:null,OrderByAsc:null,Class:class com.asentria.asm.filter.ProductDataFilter} 
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: $jacocoData of: com.asentria.asm.persistence.krp.ProductData
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1468)
...

We have an odd combination of persistence -- 1 spring-managed context which uses Hibernate directly, and one JPA-compliant context which is not managed by spring, but which also uses Hibernate for the implementation.

I know EclEmma is injecting the jacocoData field, but I have no idea how to correct the problem.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions, including ideas how how to even troubleshoot this.

Comment: And... the eclemma team fixed the problem in the April 9 release, making this moot.

Comment: On my side i stil have the same problem (with a different setup : Eclipse + ECLEmma 2.1.4 + Infinispan with a transaction manager configured), java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.common.CoordinatorEnvironmentBean.set$jacocoData([Z) (whereas my test cases are working fine on their own, it's only with ECLEmma that i get this error)

Comment: This is still a problem much of the time.  I finally ended up instrumenting my code with ant, running my tests from Eclipse, then generating the output from ant again. There doesn't appear to be any reliable work-around.

Answer (score 1):

Try to exclude all problem packages in Preferences

```
Java/Code Coverage/Excludes
```

I can successfully run tests with com.arjuna.* added to this setting.